# Using SQLite with Visual Studio 2008 and Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, sqlite

Any one know decent way to reference a SQLite database using the above mentioned tools? I tried using ODBC (the SQLite driver) but while the connection is good, I get no data returned. Like I can't see any tables in Data Connection (VS 2008). Is there a better way?

*Edit: corrected typos*

Comment: Why is Silverlight included in the question title? SQLLite is not yet ported to Silverlight 2, and what you do on the server side doesn't really matter for the Silverlight client application.

Answer (score 6):

Joel Lucsy: That implementation of SQLite is a mixed-mode assembly which is not supported by Silverlight.  Only a pure managed implementation would work under the Silverlight CLR.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the ADO driver for SQLite?

There is a great quick start guide (thanks to another thread here) that you can get here:
http://web.archive.org/web/20100208133236/http://www.mikeduncan.com/sqlite-on-dotnet-in-3-mins/

Answer (score 2):

The MIT licensed [C#-SQLite](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite) might be the right solution. It's a complete managed port of SQLite, so it can be used with Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

You should give [Siaqodb](http://siaqodb.com/) a try. I haven't tested it but they mention that is works with Silverlight OOB apps and even give you a tutorial [here](http://siaqodb.com/?p=174).
It's commercial software, but a 30 day trial is available.